# Bootstrap 3 - changed navbar height, but the responsive version didn't change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I lowered the height of my top navbar with the following code:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top:10px !important; padding-bottom:10px   !important;}
.navbar {min-height:40px !important}
```

This worked fine.
However, when I shrink my browser window to test the responsiveness, the navbar snaps back out to the full (default) 50px height.

I'm not familiar enough with the code to find what I'm looking for. Can anyone help me out? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a media query

```
@media (max-width:768px){
.navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top:10px !important; padding-bottom:10px   !important;}
.navbar {min-height:40px !important}
}
```

You may have to include height to be auto for what ever is over writing it. So height:auto or height:40px,

### UPDATED

Sorry the above may not work, try this:

```
@media (max-width:768px){
.navbar-nav > li > a {padding-top:10px !important; padding-bottom:10px   !important;}
.navbar {max-height:40px !important; min-height:30px}
}
```

Your using min height to limit the minimum height, when you should be using max height